# Drupal 8 Contextual Filter Based Upon Current User

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters, drupal-views-relationship

Somehow I am not getting it.

I have created a Taxonomy of Organizations.  I have then added a custom required field to my User accounts call "Organization".  I would like to create a view where the currently logged in user can only see a list of people that belongs to the same Organization as the currently logged in user and no others.

I have created the view just fine, and the list of users appears fine, but I cannot get the filtering and relationships to only show me the only the users that belong to the same Organization as the currently logged in user.

I could do this in SQL in like 2 seconds, but for some reason I am not getting how to do it in the Drupal interface.

I am running Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a contextual filter `User ID` (to get the current user)
   [image]
   [image]
2. Add a relationship `Taxonomy term referenced from field_organization` (to get the taxonomy term referenced by current user)
   [image]
3. Add a relationship `User using field_organization` (to get the users referencing to the Organization taxonomy at step 2)
   [image]
4. Change the relationship of all **fields** to `field_organization`
   [image]
5. If you want to exclude the current user from the results, add another contextual filter `User ID` with `field_organization` relationship
   [image]
   Remember to scroll down and check the `Exclude`
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This works.  However, I am not sure what is really going on here so I am having difficulty figuring things out.  Now I want to extend it.  Each user has an organization, and a parent organization field.  Both fields use the same taxonomy.  I want the currently logged in user to see a list of users that have the same organization and parent organization as the currently logged in users organization.  Does that makes sense?

Comment: Here is a SQL statement that can help demonstrate what I want.  I know this is not a valid SQL statement for drupal, it is just for illustration.

SELECT * FROM users WHERE current_logged_in_user.organization = users.organization OR current_logged_in_user.organization = users.parent_organization;

Comment: @karozans I understand. But I think it can't be done through Drupal view interface. You can implement some custom code to alter the view query.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the help.  Actually I think I can get it to work by linking the current user organization to the parent organization of the user they are creating and it seems to do what I want it to do.